# How to transfer video as rtp stream with least delay by FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I use AXIS M1045-LW supporting rtsp/http access, and my Windows 10 PC can access to the camera through LAN.

I would like to transfer the video as rtp with keeping H.264 codec which is supported by the camera.

---

Image

[Camera] == (rtsp or http) ==> [FFmpeg on Win10] == (rtp) ==>

---

When I accessed the camera through Google Chrome on my Win10 PC, there is only 1 or 2 sec delay.

However, when I tried access by the following command, I found over 10 sec delay.

How could I reduce the delay as much as possible?

---

**[Windows Command Prompt A ] (sender)**

```
C:\Users\xxxx\ffmpeg-4.3.1-2020-11-19-full_build\bin>ffmpeg -re -i rtsp://xxx:xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/axis-media/media.amp -codec:v copy -f rtp rtp://localhost:30002 -sdp_file stream.sdp

ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2020-11-19-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://xxx:xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/axis-media/media.amp':
  Metadata:
    title           : Session streamed with GStreamer
    comment         : rtsp-server
  Duration: N/A, start: 2.979633, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 2 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 4 tbc
Output #0, rtp, to 'rtp://localhost:30002':
  Metadata:
    title           : Session streamed with GStreamer
    comment         : rtsp-server
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 2 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 2 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rtp @ 000002da44da33c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -224986; changing to 0. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[rtp @ 000002da44da33c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -178194; changing to 0. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[rtp @ 000002da44da33c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -134998; changing to 0. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[rtp @ 000002da44da33c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -88201; changing to 0. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[rtp @ 000002da44da33c0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -45002; changing to 0. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=   89 fps=2.1 q=-1.0 size=     142kB time=00:00:43.01 bitrate=  27.0kbits/s speed=   1x
```

**[Windows Command Prompt B ] (receiver)**

```
C:\Users\xxx\ffmpeg-4.3.1-2020-11-19-full_build\bin>ffplay -protocol_whitelist "file,udp,rtp" stream.sdp

ffplay version 4.3.1-2020-11-19-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2003-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[sdp @ 000001832f4ecec0] decoding for stream 0 failed    0B f=0/0
Input #0, sdp, from 'stream.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : Session streamed with GStreamer
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 2 fps, 2 tbr, 90k tbn, 4 tbc
[swscaler @ 0000018336868d00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
 127.52 M-V: -0.021 fd=  12 aq=    0KB vq=   11KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Comment: I checked cpu and memory consumption. It's not heavy for the process.

Comment: I've already checked the web page  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Latency

Comment: This command shortened time to around 4 sec, but I would like to shorten more. ffplay -probesize 32 -analyzeduration 0 -fflags nobuffer -fflags discardcorrupt -flags low_delay -sync ext -framedrop -avioflags direct -protocol_whitelist "file,udp,rtp" stream.sdp